# Setting application/json content-type in script doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a fairly simple php script on my site. It basically greps a file for some text, then send it to the user as json. On my local system, it works fine. On my Reclaim Hosting site, the content-type comes out text/html. Here are the relevant lines:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json_output = json_decode(implode("\n", $matches[0]));
print_r(json_encode($json_output));
```

I set my php.ini to:

```
output_buffering = Off
```

php 7.3.6. Apache 2.4.46

Comment: Check your log for `Headers already sent` warnings and fix them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Don't use `print_r`, it's a debugging tool. Just use `echo`

Comment: It's unlikely that `implode("\n", $matches[0])` produces valid JSON. Do you even need the `json_decode()` part? It's probably returning `null`. At a guess, I'd say try `echo json_encode($matches[0]);`

Comment: echo is sufficient with the implode. Just using json_encode on $match[0] leaves escaped quotes. To be clear, the script returns the right text, but the content-type is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around so much with the file that I'm not quite sure of the entire sequence, but the error log showed a header already sent, as @Barmar suggested. In the end the format was UTF-8 BOM and the BOM was doing it.

So the working output lines are now:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: To be clear a BOM in the script file triggers this.